# Experiment Equipment Supplier (for use in the Classroom & at Home)

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment

Does anyone know of an online store that sells equipment specifically designed for carrying out demos in the classroom or at home? I'm helping out a student taking college physics and chemistry. These experiments are at the undergraduate level in physics and chemistry. I know http://www.scientificsonline.com/ is one, but anyone know any others? At the moment I'm looking for a polarizing lens.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard of educational innovations.. They have physics lab materials and projects and other interesting science stuff...there is also arbor scientific for high school-like physics projects...